# Inverse function to $y(x) = x + \frac{1}{1+\mathrm e^{-x}}?$

Tags: analysis

could anyone help me with finding the inverse function to the function $$y(x) = x + \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-x}}?$$

The inverse functions to individual (separate) functions $x$ and $\dfrac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-x}}$ are easy to determine. However, the determination of the inverse function to their sum seems to be more difficult. Does anyone have some idea?

Thanks to any advice.

Comment: Functions involving $x$ and $\exp(x)$ have a tendency to include the Lambert W function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function , $W(x) = inverse\{xe^{x}\}$

Comment: @mathreadler Apparently not this one, though!

Comment: We do get $xe^{-x}$ in some places if we put the terms on the same division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no closed-form solution.  However, there is a series
solution involving powers of $e^{1-y}$, which should be good for large $y$:

$$ x = y-1+{{\rm e}^{1-y}}-2\,{{\rm e}^{2-2\,y}}+11/2\,{{\rm e}^{3-3\,y}}-{
\frac {53\,{{\rm e}^{4-4\,y}}}{3}}+{\frac {1489\,{{\rm e}^{5-5\,y}}}{
24}} + \ldots $$

Comment: Dear Robert, thank you for your answer. As in case of your colleague Jack, may I ask you for a more detailed explanation how you derived your approximation?

Comment: Write the equation, with $x = y + u$ and $t = e^{-y}$, as $$u +\frac{1}{1 + t e^{-u}} = 0$$
Then in Maple: series(RootOf(u + 1/(1+t*exp(-u)),u),t);

Comment: BTW: you might also look at [OEIS sequence A052885](https://oeis.org/A052885) and links there.

Answer (score 2):

For $x>0$ the function is bounded between $x+\frac{1}{2}$ and $x+1$, hence the inverse function is bounded between $y-\frac{1}{2}$ and $y-1$. With a step of Newton's method, a more accurate approximation of the inverse function is given by
$$ y-1+\frac{e+e^y}{e+3e^y+e^{2y-1}}.$$
What is the purpose for computing an explicit inverse function?

Comment: Dear Jack, thank you for your answer. I do not need the explicit inverse function. In fact, the approximation you proposed seems to be accurate enough for my purpose. May I ask you for a more detailed explanation how you derived your approximation?

Comment: @LubomirKlimes: I applied one step of Newton's method for finding the root of $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}-y$ with starting point $y-1$. The given expression is just $y-1-\frac{f(y-1)}{f'(y-1)}$.